# How to create new row of data dependent on whether a cell is filled

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with three sheets. The first sheet is meant to be filled in by the client , the second sheet is hidden and is populated for internal purposes and the third sheet contains information about each item.

On the first sheet, there is a long list of items and a column called "Required?" which can either be "Yes" or left blank. I would like to make it so that once an item has the "Required?" field set to "Yes", that information would be populated into the second sheet from the third sheet depending on the item name.

I am hoping there is a way to do this without VBA, but am open to it if it is the only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SMALL(IF('Sheet1'!$G$3:$G$1274="Yes",ROW('Sheet1'!$G$3:$G$1274)),ROW‌​(3:3))),"",SMALL(IF('Sheet1'!$G$3:$G$1274="Yes",ROW('Sheet1'!$G$3:$G$1274)),ROW(1‌​:1)))
```

It gives me all of the rows that have a "Yes" in them in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `IF()`,  probably with the test using the `ISNA()` and `LOOKUP()` functions.  Something like:

`=IF(NOT(ISNA(LOOKUP("Yes",B1:B5)),IFVALUE,ELSEVALUE)`

Comment: That would mean I need one row in the second sheet for every row in the first sheet. I want the second sheet to be able to detect whenever there is a "Yes" anywhere on the first sheet.

Comment: I edited the answer.  Try that.  Replace B1:B5 with your range, obviously.

Comment: This is what I ended up using:

=IF(ISERROR(SMALL(IF('Sheet1'!$G$3:$G$1274="Yes",ROW('Sheet1'!$G$3:$G$1274)),ROW(3:3))),"",SMALL(IF('Sheet1'!$G$3:$G$1274="Yes",ROW('Sheet1'!$G$3:$G$1274)),ROW(1:1)))

It gives me all of the rows that have a "Yes" in them in ascending order.